# React context between unrelated components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-context

For learning purposes I'm just trying to render this dumb example where Component `A` has a variable that creates a random number and another (unrelated) Component `B` can render it with `useContext`. I don't know how to make the provider of the context to know that the value is the variable from Component `A`.

I created another file to do the `React.createContext()`... but still don't know how to make the random number to reach there or the `App` Component to do the Provider. I know I could create the random number in `App` component and provide whatever component I want with that value, but I just want the value to be generated in Component `A` and reach Component `B`. Any ideas? Maybe its so simple I can't see it.

What I have at the moment:

Component A:

```
import React from'react';

export default function RandomNumGenerator() {

    const randomNum = Math.random();

    return(
        <h2>Your random number is:</h2>
    )
}
```

Component B:

```
import React from'react';

export default function RandomNumRenderizator() {

    return(
        <h2></h2> //Want to render the random num here
    )
}
```

App Component:

```
import React from 'react';

import RandomNumGenerator from "./FunctionalComponents/RandomNumGenerator/RandomNumGenerator";
import RandomNumRenderizator from "./FunctionalComponents/RandomNumRenderizator/RandomNumRenderizator";
import RandomNumContext from "./contexts/RandomNumContext";


export default function App() {

  return (
    <div>
      <RandomNumGenerator/>
      <RandomNumContext.Provider value={}> //Empty value as I don't know what to send
        <RandomNumRenderizator/>
      </RandomNumContext.Provider>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And the Context:

```
import React from "react";
const RandomNumContext = React.createContext(); //Don't know if there should be anything as defaultValue
export default RandomNumContext;
```

Comment: Context not work like this. You need to pass the value which can be used at any children. If you need context. Let me know will update your example

Comment: Yes, I know. But how do I pass the value if it is born in a component and I dont want it to born in App Component?

Answer (score 0):

As [**data flows down**](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#the-data-flows-down) in React, the value you wish to pass have to be in scope with the context provider, then you just need to read the context value using a hook:

```
export default function App() {
  const randomNum = Math.random();
  return (
    <>
      <RandomNumDisplay num={randomNum} />
      <RandomNumContext.Provider value={randomNum}>
        <RandomNumRenderizator />
      </RandomNumContext.Provider>
    </>
  );
}

export default function RandomNumRenderizator() {
  const randomNum = useContext(RandomNumContext);
  return <h2>{randomNum}</h2>;
}
```

Comment: And is there any way to make randomNum variable to be born not in App Component but in RandomNumDisplay?

Comment: Please read the shared link, it can "born" in NumDisplay but it still will have to call some callback which comes from `App` for passing it to the provider, as data flows down.

Comment: Oh thats what I wanted. I'll try with a callback. Thank you.